# trying to set images with Picasso, getting illegal argument exception target must not be null

Tags: android, picasso

i am tring to download a few urls with Jsoup and then set them as source urls for image view with Picasso. but i had a lot of difficulty doing so.

then i decided to just send one single hardcoded url to picasso from jSoup class which resulted to an exception

here is the code for my MainActivity

```
package com.vsoft.tsubdl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ImageView imageView;
public static ImageView imageView2;
ImageView imageView3;
ImageView imageView4;
String[] tinyurl = {"http://2tinysub.net/"};
JsonParser jsonParser;
ArrayList<ImageView> imageViewsArray;

public static Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    mContext = this;
    imageViewsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    imageViewsArray.add(imageView);
    imageViewsArray.add(imageView2);
    imageViewsArray.add(imageView3);
    imageViewsArray.add(imageView4);

    jsonParser = new JsonParser();

    try {
        jsonParser.execute(tinyurl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void setImages(){
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.mContext)
            .load(jsonParser.theUrl)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

this is my JsoupParser Activity

```
public class JsonParser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

public String[] URLS = {"","","",""};
public static String theUrl = "";
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    try {


        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://2tinysub.net/").get();

        Elements links = doc.select(".box .details ul li");

        Elements picURLS = doc.select(".details .poster img");

        Element firsimage = picURLS.first();

        theUrl = "https://i.jeded.com/i/now-you-see-me-2.135-52356.jpg";


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return theUrl;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    mainActivity.setImages();
}



}
```

i think it has something to do with the fact that i'm setting image in the setImage method.

i say this because it works fine if i do the picasso part after the Jsoup execute statement in the try block in Main Activity.

Now Please does any one has an answer for whats is wrong.

Comment: Please add some information about the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is that you're creating a new instance of MainActivity in your Asynctask: `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();`

There are a number of problems with this approach if you consider the activity lifecycle with your async task.. but to your question - For this particular case your async task just needs a reference to the Activity that starts it. You need to pass that into the async task, most likely in the constructor. If yo go that route please wrap your activity in a WeakReference so you don't cause memory pressure.

Here's what would fix it: (note that I didn't compile this so there might be typos)

```
public class JsonParser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
     private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityReference;

     public JsonParser(MainActivity activity) {
          mainActivityReference = new WeakReference(activity);
     }

     ... <your other code> 

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
          //Because the activity could be destroyed, don't store a hard reference to the activity
          //Also you should probably check to make sure the activity is in a good state
          MainActivity activity = mainActivityReference.get();
          if(activity != null) {
               activity.setImages();
          }
     }
```

Comment: i am really new to programming can you explain more?

Comment: Your JsonParser Asynctask creates it's own MainActivity instead of using the one that already exists. Due to that, the imageview is null because that activity is not active.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify things and to give you an example